# Expected area of triangle inscribed in circle

Tags: probability, geometry, euclidean-geometry, expectation, area

Given $x^2 + y^2 = 1$, fix a point $X = (-1,0)$, then draw some $\theta \sim U(0,\pi)$ and create a second point $Y = (cos \theta,sin\theta)$. I then pick a third point (called $Z$) on the circumference such that the area of the inscribed triangle is maximised. What's the expected value of this area?

Can you please help me? The euclidian distance of the base is clearly $b=\sqrt{(cos\theta + 1)^2 + sin\theta^2}$ which will help in my calculation of $A = 0.5bh$.

But what's the height? One approach seems to be to find the distance from midpoint to origin, and add that to the radius (which will give the perpendicular line distance from line $XY$ to point $Z$). So far I have that the midpoint is $((cos\theta - 1)/2,sin\theta/2)$, which should mean that the height of the triangle is $h = 1 + \sqrt{((cos\theta - 1)/2)^2+(sin\theta/2)^2}$.

Have I made any mistakes so far? Is there a better approach? I don't want to plug this into $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}bh d\theta$ to find the expectation yet, seems really messy.

Comment: Hint: $\sqrt{(1+\cos\theta)^2+\sin\theta^2} = 2\cos\frac{\theta}{2}$, $\sqrt{(1-\cos\theta)^2+\sin\theta^2} = 2\sin\frac{\theta}{2}$

Comment: @achillehui Brilliant.

Comment: @achillehui How did you do that? Any reference material online?

Comment: Before looking at your approach, I have solved this by expressing the base $b$ using the half angle $\frac{\theta}{2}$. There are usually multiple angle to look at a problem. It can look messy from one angle but simple from another angle. Try look at the problem from multiple angles before committing on any approaches.

Comment: Inside the unit circle, an inscribed triangle with maximized area must be equilateral. Therefore, $\theta$ must be $60^0$. The length of a side is therefore $\sqrt 3$ and the area of it is then equal to $\dfrac {3\sqrt 3}{4}$.

Answer (score 1):

Given $X=(-1,0)$ and $Y=(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ the inscribed triangle of maximal area is isosceles with base $XY$. Its area $a(\theta)$ is given by
$$a(\theta)={1\over 2}|XY| \bigl(|MO|+1\bigr)\ ,$$ where $M$ is the midpoint of $XY$. As $\angle(OYX)={\theta\over2}$ we therefore obtain$$a(\theta)=\cos{\theta\over2}\bigl(\sin{\theta\over2}+1\bigr)\ ,$$
hence
$$E(a)={1\over\pi}\int_0^\pi\cos{\theta\over2}\bigl(\sin{\theta\over2}+1\bigr)\>d\theta={3\over\pi}\ .$$